# How to remove or change default button style?

Tags: css, button, colors, click

[image]

If you click on that image (which is inside a button) an Alertify message pops up. This (the image above) happens when the message closes.

I have this problem wherein the button defaults back to the default button decoration. How do I prevent this from happening? I already tried the `outline: none !important` CSS element but it still does not work. Is there an "aggressive" way of getting rid of this?

EDIT: I have double-checked on the developer tools already and it seems that the `outline` CSS code has already applied. However, this problem still persist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to remove the background blue and the border. Try the following styles..
These will add a 1px wide transparent border which will change color to grey when clicked. It will turn back to transparent when click is released. 
Also the background blue color will be removed.

```
button, button:focus{
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

button:active{
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. The solution is kind of aggressive but thanks.